# Display Text Over SVG Element On Hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

So I have a simple SVG element (copied below), and I want to display text (currently within the `data-label` attribute) when the rectangle with the `bar` class is hovered over.

```
<svg width="511" height="15">
    <rect fill="#555555" height="15" stroke="#000000" width="510"></rect>
    <rect class="bar" x="2" y="2" width="434" height="11" fill="#97C115" data-label="Test-Label"></rect>
</svg>
```

There could be any number of rectangles in the SVG and the label could say anything.

Since in my situation, the entire SVG element is created in JavaScript and then printed to a HTML environment, I am able to move the label anywhere. I just want the label to appear over the rectangle or above it when hovered.

Is this at all possible, since you cannot include text within the `<rect>` element?

Comment: Why not simply create a title child element to the rect with the text in? That will appear as a tooltip.

Comment: if you only want to show a tool tip you could add `<title>your title</title>` inside the svg tag https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Something like this? You can use g to group elements.

```css
svg text {display: none;}
svg g:hover text {display: block;}
```

```html
<svg width="511" height="15">
    <rect fill="#555555" height="15" stroke="#000000" width="510"></rect>
    <g>
      <rect class="bar" x="2" y="2" width="434" height="11" fill="#97C115" data-label="Test-Label"></rect>
      <text x="0" y="15">Label 1</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: If you just want a text element to appear on hover, you can dispense with the group and set `svg text {opacity:0;}`, `svg text:hover {opacity:1;}` to avoid the `hover` event not being triggered on non-displayed text.

Comment: How would I have the text appear at the bottom of the screen or somewhere not on top of the rectangle. Is there a way I can specify where it will show up?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I think is more convenient way to do it:

```css
nav {
    position: absolute;
    top:-11px;
}

ul {
    position: relative;
}
nav li {
    display:inline;
}
nav a {
    display:inline-block;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding-right:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: white;
}
ul li:hover a {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<svg width="511" height="15">
  <rect fill="#555555" height="15" stroke="#000000" width="510"></rect>
  <rect class="bar" x="2" y="2" width="434" height="11" fill="#97C115" data-label="Test-Label"></rect>
</svg>
<nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">text_one</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">text_two</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">text_three</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Yes it's verbose but it does work. The answer could benefit from explaining the possible advantage of using `visibility:...` instead of `display:...` though.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div>svg:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.589);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

div>svg {
  margin: 10px 14px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="//at.alicdn.com/t/font_1652933_iyos793o7jk.js"></script>

<body>
  <div title="mypen">
    <svg id='drawpen' class="ative" aria-hidden="true">
       <use xlink:href="#icon-huabi"></use>
   </svg><br>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, why you think this will work? Can you please edit your post and add some explanation?

Comment: Hi, it's my first answer on stack overflow, so i am not so familiar with the comment panel.          I just add a div targe and set the property 'title' to the text i want. you can go to mdn  have more info.          Since i am a learning English, please forgive my  mistakes in comprehension.